# How to calculate Score when ball hits the ball in pygame 'Pong'

Tags: python, pygame

Recently I code a pygame `'Pong'`, I am not finish it yet because the paddles cannot move yet.

However, I occurred a problem here. Because I want to get the score which is equal to the times that ball hits the edge of the window. For my program, when the ball hits the wall, score will not add and the ball will stop moving. I don't know the reason and I want to find answer here.

Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
import pygame, sys, time,math
from pygame.locals import *


# User-defined functions

def main():

   # Initialize pygame
   pygame.init()

   # Set window size and title, and frame delay
   surfaceSize = (500, 400) # window size
   windowTitle = 'Pong' #window title
   frameDelay = 0.005 # smaller is faster game

   # Create the window
   surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
   pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)

   # create and initialize red dot and blue dot
   gameOver = False
   color1=pygame.Color('white')
   center1 = [250, 200]
   radius1=10
   speed1=[1,-1]
   location1=(50, 150)
   location2=(450, 150)
   size=(5, 100)
   rect1=pygame.Rect(location1,size)
   rect2=pygame.Rect(location2,size)
   r1=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect1)
   r2=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect2)

   # Draw objects
   pygame.draw.circle(surface, color1, center1, radius1, 0)

   # Refresh the display
   pygame.display.update()

   # Loop forever
   while True:
      # Handle events
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
         # Handle additional events

      # Update and draw objects for the next frame
     gameOver = update(surface,color1,center1,radius1,speed1,rect1,rect2)


      # Refresh the display
      pygame.display.update()

      # Set the frame speed by pausing between frames
      time.sleep(frameDelay)

def update(surface,color1,center1,radius1,speed1,rect1,rect2):
   # Check if the game is over. If so, end the game and
   # returnTrue. Otherwise, erase the window, move the dots and
   # draw the dots return False.
   # - surface is the pygame.Surface object for the window
   eraseColor=pygame.Color('Black')
   surface.fill(eraseColor)
   moveDot(surface,center1,radius1,speed1)
   pygame.draw.circle(surface,color1,center1,radius1,0)
   r1=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect1)
   r2=pygame.draw.rect(surface, color1, rect2)  
   if r1.collidepoint(center1) and speed1[0]<0:
      speed1[0]=-speed1[0]
   if r2.collidepoint(center1) and speed1[0]>0:
      speed1[0]=-speed1[0]


def moveDot(surface,center,radius,speed):
   #Moves the ball by changing the center of the ball by its speed
   #If dots hits left edge, top edge, right edge or bottom edge
   #of the window, the then the ball bounces
   size=surface.get_size()
   for coord in range(0,2):
      center[coord]=center[coord]+speed[coord]
      if center[coord]<radius:
         speed[coord]=-speed[coord]
      if center[coord]+radius>size[coord]: 
         speed[coord]=-speed[coord]

def Score(center1):
   # Score is how many times that ball hits the wall.
   Score=0
   while center1[0]==10:
      Score=Score+1
   return Score


def drawScore(center1,surface):
   FontSize=60
   FontColor=pygame.Color('White')
   score=str(Score(center1))
   String='Score : '
   font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, FontSize, True)
   surface1=font.render(String+score, True, FontColor,0)
   surface.blit(surface1,(0,0))



main()
```

Comment: You've not linked your score up to anything. You need to choose when to add a new point (probably in `moveDot`), and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. First of all, you're never calling any of the code that deals with the score. You need something to call `printscore`, I suppose (either in `update` or in `main`).

The next issue is that your `Score` function contains an infinite loop. Your `while` should probably be an `if`, since you only ever need to count one point per frame:

```
def Score(center1):
   # Score is how many times that ball hits the wall.
   Score=0
   while center1[0]==10:
      Score=Score+1
   return Score
```

Even if you fix that, it still won't really work properly. The `Score` function is only ever going to return `0` or `1`, since you're resetting the `Score` local variable each time the function is called (note, it's also a very bad idea to have a local variable with the same name as the function it's in). You probably need to use a global variable (and a `global` statement), or you need to get rid of the separate function and put the score tracking logic in your main loop where it can modify a local variable. Or you could return a specific value indicating that the score should be increased, rather than the total score. There are lots of ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand it !